# How to trace InvocationTargetException?

Tags: java, exception, osgi, bundle, invocationtargetexception

I'm running my java application as **bundle** on **osgi** framework, i made a commands to use in the console, most of them working normally a little throwing this exception :

```
osgi> create name refaat
gogo: InvocationTargetException: null
osgi>
```

as you see there is no trace provided by the *InvocationTargetException* and i don't know where is the issue here, how can i trace that exception or trace the exception it wrapped?

Answer (score 2):

After your failing command, you can run

```
$exception printstacktrace
```

or just

```
$exception
```

to get the exception information. Otherwise try the log(s) of your OSGI
runtime.

http://felix.apache.org/site/rfc-147-overview.html